# Insert new Mongo doc with Json array

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am constructing a `create` method where the params passed to the controller are in json. all my `string` fields insert into the database fine but my `Array` fields are `null`.

Here is my model (stripped to simplicity)

```
Class Model
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    field :name
    field :list, type: Array
end
```

Here is the create method

```
def create
    a = a.find(params[:some_id])
    t = a.Model.create!(my_params)
    render json: t.as_json
    end        
end

private
    def my_params
        params.permit(:name, :list)
end
```

I am also using the following headers in my POST

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Here is my input body:

```
{
    "name": "test_name",
    "list":[{ 
    "value1" : "test1",
    "value2" : "test2
    }]
}
```

Here is my current output showing the `null` array

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "56c36f5cd592ce0e70b4f7da"
  },
  "name": "test_name",
  "list": null,
  "created_at": "2016-02-16T18:50:04.472Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-02-16T18:50:04.472Z"
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this is not working

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that a friend provided me. The `params.permit` call needs to whitelist the acceptable attributes for `list`

For example:  `params.permit(:name, :list [:value1])` other than this, the other work around if whitelist cannot be static is use

```
def my_params    
    params.permit!     
    params.permit(:name, :list)
end
```

This will allow all.